# Anonymous types LinQ - Check for null value - Exception

Tags: c#, linq, null, anonymous

I've been googled for a while and tried various types of combinations for my problem.

I want to fill my Gridview with results from my Anonymous type. The first run in the "loop" goes well, because all the variables has some actual value.

But the second time to fill row number 2 throws: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

This is becuase i probably assign a anonymous object to null and the gridview cant handle it.
I've tried to work out some solutions but nothing yet has worked out.

Is there a secret passageway to understand LinQ correctly?

This is my code right now:

```
var filteredlist = from info in list // List from external
                   select new
                   {
                       Question = info.QuestionText ?? "Test",
                       CorrectAnswer = info.CorrectAnswer.OptionText ?? "Test",
                       WrongAnswer1 = info.WrongAnswer1.OptionText ?? "Test",
                       WrongAnswer2 = info.WrongAnswer2.OptionText ?? "Test", //Throws Error
                       WrongAnswer3 = info.WrongAnswer3.OptionText ?? "Test" //Throws Error
                   };

GridView1.DataSource = filteredlist;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This is my tries to get it to work.

```
var filteredlist = from info in list // list from external
                   select new
                   {
                       Question = info.QuestionText == null ? "Test" : info.QuestionText,
                       CorrectAnswer = info.CorrectAnswer.OptionText == null ? "Test" : info.CorrectAnswer.OptionText,
                       WrongAnswer1 = info.WrongAnswer1.OptionText == null ? "Test" : info.WrongAnswer1.OptionText,
                       WrongAnswer2 = info.WrongAnswer2.OptionText == null ?  "Test" : info.WrongAnswer2.OptionText, //Throws Error
                       WrongAnswer3 = info.WrongAnswer3.OptionText == null ? "Test" : info.WrongAnswer3.OptionText, //Throws Error
                   };


GridView1.DataSource = filteredlist;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Second try

```
var filteredlist = from info in list // list from external
                   select new
                   {
                       Question = info.QuestionText != null ? "Test" : info.QuestionText,
                       CorrectAnswer = info.CorrectAnswer.OptionText != null ? "Test" : info.CorrectAnswer.OptionText,
                       WrongAnswer1 = info.WrongAnswer1.OptionText != null ? "Test" : info.WrongAnswer1.OptionText,
                       WrongAnswer2 = info.WrongAnswer2.OptionText != null ? "Test" : info.WrongAnswer2.OptionText, //Throws Error
                       WrongAnswer3 = info.WrongAnswer3.OptionText != null ? "Test" : info.WrongAnswer3.OptionText, //Throws Error
                   };

GridView1.DataSource = filteredlist;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Please pay more attention when formatting code in your question. It makes a huge difference to readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to check if `WrongAnswer`s are not null, like so:

```
from info in list
where info != null
select new
{
    Question = info.QuestionText ?? "Test",
    CorrectAnswer = info.CorrectAnswer.OptionText ?? "Test",
    WrongAnswer1  = info.WrongAnswer1 !=null ? info.WrongAnswer1.OptionText : "Test",
    WrongAnswer2  = info.WrongAnswer2 !=null ? info.WrongAnswer2.OptionText : "Test", 
    WrongAnswer3  = info.WrongAnswer3 !=null ? info.WrongAnswer3.OptionText : "Test"
};
```

I love to use generic methods for readability, like this:

```
public string DefaultIfNull<TValue>(TValue value, Func<TValue, string> selector) where TValue : class
{
    if(value != null)
        return selector(value);
    return "Test"; //you can make resut generic too
}
```

Now you can:

```
Func<Answer,string> optionTextSelector = answer => answer.OptionText;

from info in list
where info != null
select new
{
    Question = info.QuestionText ?? "Test",
    CorrectAnswer = DefaultIfNull( info.CorrectAnswer, optionTextSelector ),
    WrongAnswer1  = DefaultIfNull( info.WrongAnswer1,  optionTextSelector ),
    WrongAnswer2  = DefaultIfNull( info.WrongAnswer2,  optionTextSelector ),
    WrongAnswer3  = DefaultIfNull( info.WrongAnswer3,  optionTextSelector ),
};
```

Main idea is not to obfuscate and not to make your solution **too** complex using functional approach.

Comment: This solved the issue. I didnt think of that, the "local" variables "optiontext" where the only that showed "null"
Thank you! i appreciate all the help!(from others to).

Answer (score 0):

`info.WrongAnswer2` is most likely `null`. Try:

```
WrongAnswer2 = info.WrongAnswer2 == null ? "Nothing To See Here" : 
    info.WrongAnswer2.OptionText ?? "Test"
```

Likewise with `info.WrongAnswer3`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably checking the wrong property, try checking `info.WrongAnswer2` and `info.WrongAnswer3` for null before checking `OptionText`.